# Java SQL Syntax Translator

Tags: sql, oracle, mariadb, mariasql, translators

Is there a reliable library or package for Java that can translate from one SQL syntax to another?

I did some Google searching and found http://www.sqlines.com/online

I'm curious if there is something like this that I can use programmatically to do like 500 queries in bulk. Specifically I'm interesting in going from Oracle to MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

Variants of SQL are so extreme that I would doubt if there is a translator that does more than half the job.  And you may have to make lots of changes to the `CREATE TABLE`.  And Oracle has lots of features that simply do not exist in MariaDB.

So...  You are better off learning both variants and hand-coding the replacement.  This may include removing old cruft (a good thing) and/or having to invent new wheels (possibly a challenge).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use jOOQ. It supports many backends, and recently got a parser that can parse a superset of the dialects that jOOQ supports. It is currently marked as experimental, but could still be useful for a one-time translation job.

Here are the docs for the parser: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/

And here is an online translator you can experiment with to see if it suits your needs: https://www.jooq.org/translate/

It also supports something called a parsing connection, which is a wrapper around a JDBC connection that translates SQL to your dialect of choice on-the-fly: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/parsing-connection/

Comment: Please do not provide answers to questions requesting off-site resources; they are off-topic.

Comment: Notice that the translation functionality is available as a command line tool as well, so this could definitely help translating a bulk of SQL statements: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-cli